# Laravel RESTful resource route adds percentages to URI

Tags: php, laravel

I have a user RESTful resource route in my Laravel App.

```
Route::resource('backbone.users', 'backbone\UserController');
```

for the the CRUD operations.

Unfortunately, I get following URIs:

[image: I get the {backbone} in the URI that results in %backbone% in the browser]

I get {backbone} in the URI that results in %backbone% in the browser but
I want the URL like **dev.domain/backbone/users** NOT **dev.domain/backbone/%backbone%/users**

I would need to redirect like:

```
return Redirect::intended('backbone/{backbone}/users');
```

How come?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell by the screenshot (or maybe my eyes aren't great) but it looks like `backbone/{backbone}/users`. If this is the case, that's intended, the `{}` are indicating that it can take a variable in this position.

So it might be `return Redirect::intended('background/1/users');`

The controller method to go with it, in this case `index` of `UserController` will receive that variable as its argument.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal for Laravel.  The {} in your routes list represent url variables.

Take this route for example:

```
/users/{user}/edit
```

To use this route you would navigate to

```
/users/1/edit
```

Assuming you have your controller method setup similar to:

```
public function edit($userId)
{

}
```

The $userId variable would contain '1' from the url.  Definitely checkout the docs for more on Laravel routing

Comment: That's understandable for edit, update, delete and so on but not for the index one for the overview. there shouldn't be {}. If I make the resource route without the .users I get the write URL (/backbone) without the {}